# How to return the location of my mouse pointer in java?

Tags: java

I know with the robot class I can move my mouse to an (x,y) coordinate but is there a way to return this (x,y) coordinate that my mouse is currently hovering over?  Or possibly a way to see the (x,y) coordinate that I have last clicked.

I'm using the returns to map out a specific order of coordinates that need to be clicked and I don't want to guess which pixel it is on a 4k screen.

Comment: If you are handling an event like 'click' you could use `event.getX()` and `event.getY()`

Comment: What is the 'robot' class? What libraries/modules are you currently using to move the mouse?

Comment: @Michael0x2a: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Answer (score 1):

```
PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
Point b = a.getLocation();
int x = (int) b.getX();
int y = (int) b.getY();
Robot r = new Robot();
r.mouseMove(x + 100 , y + 100 );
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be "cooler" if you really move the mouse :P? Your current example move the mouse to the current position. Something like `r.mouseMove(x + 100, y + 100);`, just to show how this `mouseMove` method moves the mouse on the screen.